# Post representation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Question 1: If there a post such as this one. How would I represent it in JavaScript? I thought was JSO and parse. Other programming language like C++ and JAVA a main function and have map references but where does JavaScript store it's objects?

Question 2: Oh and do I add Event Handlers to each of the HTML representatives elements?

Comment: So you are looking for a break down of your post into a template with code?

Comment: I guess, something like a simple template that I can get my head around. People are saying store objects in variables but it's I was also told its better to hash them and create references to them in an array.. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic data structure in JavaScript is [the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), you would probably use one (or, more likely, a structured collection of them along with more specific data structures such as arrays) to describe the data structure that makes up a webpage.

The main function in Java and C++ is the entry point to the program. In JavaScript, the entry point is the top of the program.

JavaScript stores its objects in memory and references to them in variables and as properties of objects.

You would only add an event handler to an HTML Element object if you wanted to listen for an event on it.

> People are saying store objects in variables but it's I was also told its better to hash them and create references to them in an array.

You use the data type most appropriate for the data you are working with.

If you have a:

- simple piece of data, use a variable.
- collection of ordered data, use an array (or maybe a Set if you are using ES6)
- collection of unordered data, use an object (or maybe a Map if you are using ES6)

… and nest to whatever level makes sense.

You might also create a custom data type with a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) or (if you are using ES6) a [Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: That makes sense. I'll select it as the best answer once it lets me.

Comment: @LemmyTauer — No. (a) I said *script* and not HTML document. (b) The start of the script is still the entry point. The script might bind event listeners, but it has to start at the top of the script and run the code that binds them before they can trigger. The exception is when you use intrinsic event attributes (which are awful things with some nasty gotchas), and even then, most of the time, you are calling functions which you define in the script which executes from the top.

Comment: @LemmyTauer — No, I'm not. I simplified slightly by not discussing hoisting (but what you are talking about has nothing to do with hoisting).

Comment: If we've reached the point where you are going to accuse me of trolling, I'm not going to engage with you further.

Comment: Isn't the entry point when the so-called main function starts? Otherwise it's objects are created and allocation of memory.

Comment: @WhiteLotus — There is no "main function", JavaScript is not C. There is the top of the script. Here [is an example](http://jsbin.com/kerito/1/edit?html,output) that doesn't define any functions at all (although it calls a couple supplied by the browser to the JS environment).

Comment: @LemmyTauer - The edits made after the start of the commenting have nothing to do with anything mentioned in the comments.